# How do I add category to my database query?

Tags: php, mysql

Search works, and pagination works, but I need to have category results not all.
Like this: WHERE (category: 'admin').
How do I put that in here so it works? Right now when I put category in, search won't work.

```
$searchQuery = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users
                                         WHERE (category = 'admin'), 
                                         name LIKE '%{$request}%'
                                         OR lastnameLIKE '%{$request}%'
                                         OR username LIKE '%{$request}%' 
                                         LIMIT " . (($page* 5) - 5) . ",5");
```

Solution:

```
 $searchQuery = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users
                                          WHERE category = 'admin' AND
                                          name LIKE '%{$request}%'
                                          LIMIT " . (($page* 5) - 5) . ",5");
```

Comment: What did you put in that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `(category = 'admin')` wrapped with `( )` and you use a `,` instead of `AND`

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE category = 'admin' 
AND name LIKE '%{$request}%'
OR lastnameLIKE '%{$request}%'
OR username LIKE '%{$request}%' 
LIMIT " . (($page* 5) - 5) . ",5"
```